# Google web service null safety issue

Tags: dart, google-maps, geolocation, flutter-dependencies, google-places-api

I'm trying to look for the nearest hospitals on button press in flutter but since the google web service doesn't support it. I couldn't figure a solution out. any help will be appreciated.

I asked Chat Gpt since I was stuck with little to no guides or tutorials. I'm still a beginner so please make the solutions as detailed as possible.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' as geoLoc;
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart'as loc;
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart'as places;
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';



class MapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapsScreenState createState() => _MapsScreenState();
}

class _MapsScreenState extends State<MapsScreen> {
  late Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  LocationPermission? _locationPermission;

  locateParamedicPosition() async {
    Position cPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: geoLoc.LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = cPosition;

    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(
        currentPosition!.latitude, currentPosition!.longitude);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
        target: latLngPosition, zoom: 15);

    mapController!.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  isGranted() async {
    _locationPermission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

    if (await Permission.locationAlways
        .request()
        .isDenied) {
      // Use location.
      _locationPermission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }
    // if (await Permission.locationAlways.request().isGranted) {
    //   // Use location.
    //
    // }
  }
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  double bottomPaddingMap = 0;
  double topPaddingMap = 0;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;
  loc.Location _location = loc.Location();
  late LatLng _currentPosition;
  List<PlacesSearchResult> _places = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      _currentPosition = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude!, currentLocation.longitude!);
      _getNearbyPlaces();
    });
    bottomPaddingMap = 190;
    topPaddingMap = 450;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;
    _controller.complete(controller);

    locateParamedicPosition();
    isGranted();
  }
  void _getNearbyPlaces() async {
    final places.GoogleMapsPlaces placesApi = places.GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: "AIzaSyCeYZDeBlwdcDa4X0M31k27gWsdhjlqx50");
    final location = places.Location(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
    final result = await placesApi.searchNearbyWithRadius(location, 5000, type: "hospital");
    setState(() {
      _places = result.results ?? [];
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: GoogleMap(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: topPaddingMap, bottom: bottomPaddingMap),
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 14.0,
          ),
          markers: Set.from(_places.map((place) {
            return Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(place.id),
              position: LatLng(
                place.geometry.location.lat,
                place.geometry.location.lng,
              ),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: place.name,
                snippet: place.vicinity,
              ),
            );
          })),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
      _getNearbyPlaces();
    },
    child:
    Icon(Icons.search),
        ),
    );
  }

}
```